# Close a div by clicking a button inside the div

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to close the main div by clicking close button which is inside that div.
What JavaScript code do I need to write in iframe to achieve it?

Main Page :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showhide()
 {
       var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
 }
</script>
<style>
#newpost {
z-index: 1;
display:none;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}
#myframe {
z-index: 2;
position:fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="newpost" id="newpost">
<div class="myframe" id="myframe"><iframe id="signup_frame1" width="750" height="420" src="iframe.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
<FONT COLOR="#696969" onclick="showhide()"><span style="cursor:pointer">Show div</span></font>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.html  :-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showhide()
 {
       var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
if (div.style.display !== "none") {
    div.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<FONT COLOR="#696969" onclick="showhide()"><span style="cursor:pointer">Close div</span></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in iFrame: `var div=parent.document.getElementById("newpost")` or better: `parent.showhide()`

Comment: As a side remark, You really shouldn't use font tag, use CSS for styling combined with semantic HTML instead...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since your iFrame is on the same domain there is a way to do this. For example,

```
<div id="close">
    <iframe src="/HTMLPage2.htm">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Then inside the iFrame something like this should do the trick:

```
<script>
    function closeDiv() {
        window.parent.document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<input value="close div" type="button" onclick="closeDiv()"/>
```

Specific to the code that is inside your iFRAME, it needs to be this instead:

```
    function showhide() {
        var div = window.parent.document.getElementById("newpost");
        if (div.style.display !== "none") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

All said and done, your code should be this:

Main page -

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showhide() {
            var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {
                div.style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                div.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #newpost
        {
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #myframe
        {
            z-index: 2;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="newpost" id="newpost">
        <div class="myframe" id="myframe">
            <iframe id="signup_frame1" width="750" height="420" src="/iframe.htm" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <font color="#696969" onclick="showhide()"><span style="cursor: pointer">Show div</span></font>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe -

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide() {
        var div = window.parent.document.getElementById("newpost");
        if (div.style.display !== "none") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<FONT COLOR="#696969" onclick="showhide()"><span style="cursor:pointer">Close div</span></font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding your statement "iFrames are evil and you should always avoid them" - this is pretty misleading. There are circumstances where you never want to use iframes and circumstances where you almost always want to use iframes. Even if the OP shouldn't be using iframes in his specific code, that doesn't make them evil.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I respectfully and wholeheartedly disagree. iFrames cause all kinds of problems- styling issues (especially on mobile), the accidental inclusion of duplicate tags for web tracking, and performance issues because they drive up load time, and that is especially significant when browsing on a slow mobile or rural broadband connection. If I had I my own web development company, I would ban the use of the tag outright.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaDannemann but It is not working for me, can you try this with my code on your PC ?

Comment: @Plasha There must be something else going on, the code I posted is fine, but I will check against yours as requested.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann I respectfully and rebuttalfully disagree. There is a reason that Facebook, Twitter, YouTube, etc. use iFrames for their embed codes - namely that nothing from outside of the iFrame can accidentally mess with what's inside the iFrame, so the embed always has a consistent look. In my opinion iFrames are almost like an HTML5 equivalent to a Flash applet - they are there for when a specific block of content is logically separate from its page, and should be isolated as such. I would recommend that OP read more on iFrames himself and form his own opinion though.

Comment: @Plasha It works just fine for me once adjusted. However, I was confused for a second why I could not see the text of the IFrame. It turns out you have it set to display none by default in your CSS.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister You do have a point about widgets that are hosted externally. That makes sense, but given my background as a specialist for analytics, I still think IFrames are evil... can't detect and record any interactions with iFrames not native to the domain and they often cause havoc on the stats.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Thanks, I will wait for your answer, please try this code with mine, I am trying this but not working.
and Joshua using Iframes saves some coding :)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I love iframes

Comment: @Plasha I tested it. The iFrame is set to display none by default, but once I unhide it and click with the modified JavaScript, it works just fine.

Comment: @Plasha If you love iFrames that's kind of scary too! ;P iFrames are like a hex wrench - you shouldn't be using them for everything, but there are specific cases when they are the best tool!

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Thank you very much, Can you share whole coding to me ? you can send it direct to my email nastukdiplasha@gmail.com

I am still trying to fix this bug but I'm not getting any solution :(

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann I didn't got it, "iFrame is set to display none by default" set borders to 1 :p

Comment: @Plasha Unfortunately, I cannot at this time send it to you, but I can update my answer. I do not know why is is not working for you, because it is working for me just fine. What browser are you testing against?

Comment: Google Chrome @JoshuaDannemann

Please help me when you will be free, and thank you again

Comment: @Plasha Full code posted... if it is still not working for you, make sure to clear the cache in Google Chrome... that's probably why it's not working... Chrome has a really aggressive cache and it's probably using old code.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaDannemann It is working now. I just Tested it in Microsoft Edge and IE, Code works fine in other all other browser. First time I am facing this problem with GC. Sorry. I was needed to check my files with other browser's last night, I was checking in GC all the time, sorry and Thank you

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann I cleared my caches, cookies and everything from GC, I thought you are using latest GC version therefore I also upgraded my GC but that code is not working in GC, I am totally shocked. It is working in IE and MS Edge but not in GC :(

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann
now getting your point, "Don't use lot Iframes they are horrible "

Comment: LOL! Yes! Don't use them often, but still... it is good to know how to use them. Anyway, the reason it won't work in GC is because you need to clear the cache. On the Omnibox in the top right corner click > more tools > clear browsing data, and then clear the cache. You can leave cookies and other stuff alone.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jQuery:

```
$('#signup_frame1').load(function(){

    var iframe = $('#signup_frame1').contents();

    iframe.find("#Close_btn_ID").click(function(){
           $("#myframe").hide();
    });
});
```

Here, ***"#Closebtn_ID"*** will be the ID of the Button inside iFrame where you want to attach the click handler.

Comment: Thank you @mechanicals but in my College teacher haven't taught us how to use jquery, does I need to include any jquery file from google ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp . This link should help you out to include jquery. Its just a library written in javascript.

Comment: Using jquery to achieve this is hugely overkill and thus would be a bad practice. If you did this and I was the teacher, you wouldn't get a very good grade.

Comment: @LaurentS. ahaha, but I want to learn Jquery maybe after 1 year teacher will teach us :( I am want to learn more from outside, I will try to learn from w3school

Comment: @Plasha jQuery is not bad as such, but including a ~100KB library to perform a task that only needs a few lines of javascript should always be a no-go. I also consider it better to learn a bit of javascript THEN move on to  libraries. That way you get a better idea of what's going on behind the scenes, as you could in some case have a single line of jQuery resulting in a lot of JS with a possible impact on perfs.

Comment: @Plasha You should listen to LaurentS. Jquery is useful for many things, but it's become so ubiquitous now that many developers are becoming lazy using it and seem to have forgotten that pure JavaScript can do anything that Jquery can do. It's good for you to learn using JavaScript first and later stick to Jquery when it just happens to get the job done with less code.

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann Yes, I am waiting, maybe this year or next year teacher will teach us.. :) Thank you fro suggestions. I also want to learn Jquery